# PowerPoint 2013 crashes becasue of add-in?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, code-access-security, powerpoint-2013

I have created an add-in in PowerPoint 2013 (***.ppam** format). This works fine when I open the actual add-in file. But when I add it to PowerPoint 2013 to auto load it via registry,

> **Key:** HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\PowerPoint\AddIns\MyAddin
>
> **REG_DWORD Value:** ***"AutoLoad"*** - 1
>
> **REG_SZ Value:** ***"Path"*** - C:\Documents\MyAddin.ppam

After that when opening PowerPoint 2013, PowerPoint crashes. This issue only occurs in PowerPoint 2013. It works fine in previous versions. What is the issue here?

I tried sample add-in with one line of code and it still crashes PowerPoint 2013.

Comment: By any chance do you have Kaspersky's antivirus software loaded on the PC with PPT 2013?   If so, google "kaspersky powerpoint addin" (remove the quotes) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. I tried on a computer without Kaspersky and it did not crash.

Comment: That'd be the good news.  The bad news is that unless Kaspersky has cleaned up its act, uninstalling it and even using their removal tool doesn't help;  apparently reformatting and reinstalling everything is the only fix.

Comment: Some more info from Kaspersky's forum:  http://forum.kaspersky.com/lofiversion/index.php/t277011.html   (the short version:  they don't care)